# Rapid virtualization with "fork from here" to a new LXC/docker container

Tags: docker, virtualization, lxc, lxd

Looking at LXC and docker, they both require some kind of template or image to run a container. Is there a technology that allows to just fork current session into parallel world and commit or discard all the changes at the end?

For example:

```
$ echo "test"> test
$ fork-from-here just-a-name
just-a-name$ rm test
just-a-name$ cat test
cat: test: No such file or directory
just-a-name$ commit
container "just-a-name" state saved..
just-a-name$ logout
$ cat test 
test
```

Anything close to that?

Comment: Start a container instance. Make whatever changes you want. You can then snapshot that image (see docker "commit" command) and startup other copies of it. I would advise reading the docker basics guide: https://docs.docker.com/articles/basics/

Comment: @MarkO'Connor, docker [failed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker.io/+bug/1366509) for me.

Comment: Try running docker as follows "docker run --rm -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash" (prefix the command with sudo is you must). The error you're getting is odd... Looks like a broken image... See : http://kimh.github.io/blog/en/docker/gotchas-in-writing-dockerfile-en/#exec_format_error

Comment: @MarkO'Connor, looks like the problem is that Docker chooses to support only amd64 hosts and I am running i686.

Comment: @techtonik Yes Docker is made only for 64-bit platform.